# How to display string in CollectionView Cell?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I need to display a string in my `UICollectionViewCell`. I have created a custom view cell. But whenever I run the application it shows "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return places.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PlaceCollectionViewCell

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00).cgColor

   //cell.placeLabel.tintColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.278, green: 0.694, blue: 0.537, alpha: 1.00).cgColor

    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 35
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = true

    //cell.placeLabel.text = places[indexPath.row] as! String
    cell.placeLabel.text = places[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: At what line do you get the error?  Can you also show the code for PlaceCollectionViewCell?  Ensure that you set the identifier of the cell to "Cell" in storyboard.

Comment: I get error at this line "cell.placeLabel.text = places[indexPath.row]"

Comment: Can you also show your code for PlaceCollectionViewCell?

Comment: @RakeshMohan Show the initialization of `places` array.

Comment: No, the code for your custom collectionview class, where placeLabel is defined

Comment: Can you print the value at that `places[indexPath.row]` and check if it present? If it is a `NSMutableArray` have you initialized it? Is the `UILabel` connected to its outlet?

Comment: there are two possibilities here, 1. Your `placeLabel` not IBOutlet properly. 2. `places array` doesn't have proper value.

Comment: @NiravD var places = ["name1","name2","name3"]

Comment: @RakeshMohan Check you IBOutlet `placeLabel` is properly connected with your cell

Comment: @NiravD Yes it;s connected properly. Please helm me guys.

Comment: @CarienvanZyl import UIKit

class PlaceCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    
    IBOutlet weak var placeLabel: UILabel!
   
    IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        
    }
       override func awakeFromNib() {
        
        self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.frame.size.width/2
        
        self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

Comment: Can't see the problem either.  If you add a breakpoint just before cell.placeLabel.text = places[indexPath.row].  Can you see what the values of places and placeLabel is?  I.o.w which one is nil and hence produce the error.

Comment: @CarienvanZyl The places are printing in number of items in section method but not in cell for item at indexpath mehod.

Comment: Do you mean it is nil there? I would have thought that places would be fine, since places.count did not give an error.

Comment: @CarienvanZyl : No I am sorry. It's printing there also. But the error is same.

Comment: @CarienvanZyl I have added a breakpoint just before cell.placeLabel and the value is printing. But I get error at "cell.placeLabel.text = places[indexPath.row] "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130384/discussion-between-carien-van-zyl-and-rakesh-mohan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From our discussion in chats...

Ensure that the nib file used for the custom cell is linked up properly with the collectionView, by doing this line in viewDidLoad.

```
constCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName:"PlaceCollectionViewCell", bundle:nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```